# how to configure a proxy for applications

Tags: windows, proxy

I am currently in University Room, and to connect to the Internet i have to go through a proxy (which is easily doable on a browser) but I can not access a variety of applications such as Steam, Battle.net.

Is there a way to configure the proxy for applications that do not support this setting? (From windows directly?)

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think this is off-topic and would be better posted on http://superuser.com

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought it was for everything ><
Thanks you